# Drupal Twitter widget not showing tweets

Tags: social-network

Hi i am working on drupal site And i have noticed Twitter profile widget is no more working and its showing an empty space in the tweets block. I checked developer pane i have found following notices.

TWITTER WIDGET: The Twitter API v1.0 is deprecated, and this widget has ceased functioning. widget.js:1

TWITTER WIDGET: You can replace it with a new, upgraded widget from https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/user?screen_name=people_10 widget.js:1

TWITTER WIDGET: For more information on alternative Twitter tools, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites

Do you have any suggestions to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Use module's issue queue to request update to supported API, or rewrite it yourself and post a patch to issue queue.

Comment: The open issues page of the version7:
https://drupal.org/node/1967628

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide enough information. Which module? Which version of Drupal? If you're on Drupal 7 and you're using the [Twitter](https://drupal.org/project/twitter) module, you must carefully follow the documented installation procedure, documented [here](https://drupal.org/node/1346824).

Comment: Hi Kyle, I am using drupal 6.0 and module is Twitter profile widget  https://drupal.org/project/twitter_profile_widget

Comment: I'd gave the twitter project I mentioned a look, albeit I've stopped using D6 some time ago. Must you use the one you've mentioned? Twitter did change its authentication routines, so I'd verify the D6 version follows the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is no longer supporting API V1.0 .Those who use API v1.0 should move to embedded timelines option.

You can create your twitter widget [here](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new)

[Reference link](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/planning-for-api-v1-retirement)